# Why can't a bit field be split between different underlying types?

Tags: c++, bit-fields

Why does the sizes of these two structs differ?

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct WordA
    {
        uint32_t address           : 8;
        uint32_t data             : 20;
        uint32_t sign              : 1;
        uint32_t stateMatrix : 2;
        uint32_t parity            : 1;
    };

    struct WordB
    {
        uint8_t address;
        uint32_t data             : 20;
        uint8_t sign              : 1;
        uint8_t stateMatrix : 2;
        uint8_t parity            : 1;
    };
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Somehow `WordB` occupies 6 bytes instead of four, while `WordA` occupies exactly 32 bits.
I assumed that given the sum of used bits inside a struct would yield both structs to be of the same size. Apparently I am wrong, but I cannot find an explanation why.
[Bit fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) page shows only examples when all of the struct members are of the same type, which is a case of `WordA`.

Can anybody explain, why the sizes don't match and if it is according to the standard or implementation-defined?

Comment: bitfield is implementation specific, but generally, bitfield doesn't split between different underlying types.

Comment: @Jarod42 `bitfield doesn't split between different underlying types.` I figured that might be the reason, but  I would like to have some reference to the standard.

Comment: @Jarod42 I've renamed the question to be specific.

Comment: How should the compiler see that its allowed to join `address` which is not a bitfield with the rest of the bitfields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't a bit field be split between different underlying types?

It **can** in the sense that standard allows it.

It **wasn't** because that's what the language implementer (or rather, the designer of the ABI) chose. This decision may have been preferred because it may make the program faster or the compiler easier to implement.

Here is the standard quote:

> [class.bit]
>
> ... Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined.
> Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined.
> Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit.

Comment: Could you please refer to the standard? I will accept your answer in that case.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Added quote.

Comment: I think that standard quote proves the opposite. The bits field have to be packed into their **own** addressable unit, e.g. a `uint32_t` which does not overlap the non-bitfield `uint8_t address;`

Comment: @MSalters it will not overlap it even if it was a bitfield.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: If they were all bitfields, the bits themselves would not overlap, but the bitfields would be allocated from the same addressable unit. But in `WordB` only 24 of the `uint32_t` bits are used, so there are 8 unused bits.